# shift left until MSB is 1: loop count limit exceeded. Condition is never false

Tags: verilog

I tried to shift left the "shifted register" until it's MSB is 1. But my code doesn't work.

Compiler says

> loop count limit exceeded. Condition is never false

```
input wire [31:0] targetnumber,
...
reg [31:0] shifted;
...
shifted=targetnumber;
for(cnt = 0; shifted[31] == 0; shifted = shifted << 1)begin
   cnt = cnt + 1;
end
```

So the problem is for loop, I'm 100% sure my shifted register's MSB could reach to 1 if I do this left shifting. But compiler says NOPE bitch.

I tried `shifted[31] != 0;`, it doesn't make error, but that doesn't make a result which I intended.

Comment: Few questions to clarify: Is `targetnumber` constant? Is the for loop inside `always`? Do you want to implement this in combinational way? Since "shift register" is usually shifted one bit at one clock cycle.

Comment: Also: do you get the error in simulation or synthesis? Note that for synthesis the for loop size must be deterministic during **compile** time.

Answer (score 1):

Given not all dependencies between signals are explained/detailed I'm not sure if I understand Your code completely, but perhaps code excerpt pasted below would be of help for You.

```
for(cnt = 0; cnt < 31; cnt = cnt + 1)begin
    if (targetnumber[i])
        shift_index = 31 - cnt;
    cnt = cnt + 1;
end

assign shifted = targetnumber << shift_index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct. Consider what happens when `shifted = 0`.

This code is unlikely to be synthesizable. If you are trying to count the number of leading 0 bits in a number, a more explicit approach (e.g. writing a loop which runs 32 times and checks each bit in sequence) is preferable.